In the project for springboot+mybatis,How to solve the error:'Unable to resolve table'?
As the title,I have got trouble in the error:'Unable to resolve table sys_user',the following is my codes.
//
package com.example.nhlqu.mapper;

import com.example.nhlqu.entity.User;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.*;

import java.util.List;

@Mapper
public interface UserMapper {

    @Select("SELECT * from sys_user")
    List<User> findAll();

    @Insert("INSERT into sys_user(username, password,nickname,email,phone,address) VALUES (#{username}, #{password}," +
            " #{nickname}, #{email},#{phone}, #{address})")
    int insert(User user);

    int update(User user);

    @Delete("delete from sys_user where id = #{id}")
    Integer deleteById(@Param("id") Integer id);

    @Select("select * from sys_user where username like #{username} limit #{pageNum}, #{pageSize}")
    List<User> selectPage(Integer pageNum, Integer pageSize, String username);

    @Select("select count(*) from sys_user where username like concat('%', #{username}, '%') ")
    Integer selectTotal(String username);
}

The preceding is my codes of UserMapper.java,and the following is my codes of application.properties
spring.application.name=nhlqu
server.port=9090
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mybatis?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=123456
mybatis.mapper-locations=classpath:mapper/*.xml
mybatis.configuration.log-impl=org.apache.ibatis.logging.stdout.StdOutImpl

The following is the codes of mapper/User.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.example.nhlqu.mapper.UserMapper">
    <update id="update">
        update sys_user
        <set>
            <if test="username != null">
                username = #{username},
            </if>
            <!--            <if test="password != null">-->
            <!--                password = #{password}-->
            <!--            </if>-->
            <if test="nickname != null">
                nickname = #{nickname},
            </if>
            <if test="email != null">
                email = #{email},
            </if>
            <if test="phone != null">
                phone = #{phone},
            </if>
            <if test="address != null">
                address = #{address}
            </if>
        </set>
        <where>
            id = #{id}
        </where>
    </update>
</mapper>

The following is the codes of User.java
package com.example.nhlqu.entity;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    private Integer id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String nickname;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private String address;
}

The following is my table of sys_user.
enter image description here
Hearing that changing the SQL Dialect to MySQL can solve the error:'Unable to resolve table', I gave it a try. However, the error still existing.
enter image description here
Please help me to solve these problems, sincerely thanks!

You haven't changed the dialect. You changed something in your IDE settings not your application.
